# How to understand Kotlin documentation syntax in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

## Example

I'm hovering over a `ClassName::javaClass` instance in my kotlin/android project - and see a preview of the documentation for `javaClass`:

```
public val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>
```

## Question

Apologies if this is a basic question but **how can the above be translated?** And is there any resource for me to read that will give me a rundown of that type of documentation syntax?

Comment: Little nitpick but this is the *definition* of the property, not the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`public val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>`

This is actually extension property. Works basically the same as extension function (in fact compiler will generate extension getter function for any type inheriting from `Any`).

Simpler example, without generics:

```
val String.withPrefix: String
    get() = "_$this"

fun test() {
    println("Hello".withPrefix) // prints "_Hello"
}
```

One more example - now for generic type:

```
val <T: Number> T.hexValue: String
    get() = convertToHex(this)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val number: Double = 10.0
    println("Hex value of $number is ${number.hexValue}")
}
```

Construction you are asking is quite strange, because connects both generic and extension function. But, as you can see in fact there is just very simple construction - just looks strange.

See more about extensions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties

See more about generics: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Thankyou. Is `<T>` type?

Comment: Exactly. See second link, generic is really nice explained in kotlin docs.